# Referential Integrity Constraint Violation occurred on DbContext.Find() (Code First)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, invalidoperationexception

I am encountering a rather interesting exception. It occurred yesterday on code that had worked at some point in the past (I inherited most of the code base and the former developer is no longer with us).

I applied a workaround using `.Where()` yesterday, but since I encountered the problem again in another controller today, I decided it would be best to get to the bottom of it before it bites me somewhere unexpected.

I am getting the error below:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: A primary key
>   property that is a part of referential integrity constraint cannot be
>   changed when the dependent object is Unchanged unless it is being set
>   to the association's principal object. The principal object must be
>   tracked and not marked for deletion.

Now for the strange part. I am getting this error when I use the Find() method `DbContext.DbSet.Find(int)` with a new dbContext.

Here is the exact code. It finds the CurResponse object on line 5 without incident, but it fails and throws the exception above when it encounters the `db.CurFundings.Find(post.SelectedSourceCurFundingKey);` on line 7 below:

```
0. [HttpPost]
1. public ActionResult MatchingCur2Fundings(int id, MatchingCur2FundingsVM post, string callbackId)
2. {
3. if (ModelState.IsValid)
4. {
5. var cur = _db.CurResponses.Find(id);
6. var c2f = new Cur2FundingDataFlow();
7. c2f.SourceFunding =  _db.CurFundings.Find(post.SelectedSourceCurFundingKey);
```

I replaced `post.SelectedSourceCurFundingKey` with an integer like below:

```
7. c2f.SourceCurFunding = _db.CurFundings.Find(1);
```

And I still get the error above.

When I quickwatch `_db.CurFundings`, it returns 3 objects and one of them has a primary key of *1*.

When I quickwatch the  `db.CurFundings.Find(post.SelectedSourceCurFundingKey);` I get the error above, so it doesn't have anything to do with what is on the left side of the assignment.

I can get the item I need by replacing the `DbContext.DbSet.Find()` with `DbContext.DbSet.Where(x => x.id == id).SingleOrDefault()` as in the following:

```
c2f.SourceCurFunding = _db.CurFundings.Where(cf => cf.CurFundingKey == post.SelectedSourceCurFundingKey).SingleOrDefault();
```

The issue only occurs when I use the `Find()` method to retrieve items from the DbContext.

I am using EF CodeFirst and the majority of the current code was inherited a few months back.

I don't know if this will help, but here is the line that adds this specific object to my DbContext:

```
public DbSet<CuFunding> CurFundings { get; set; }
```

This is the only reference to the `DbContext.CurFundings` property in the application and when I look at the usages of that type, I don't see anything strange going on.

I can always just use the `.Where()` to get what I need, but I'd like to ensure that this is not a sign of deeper problems.

## Edit 1

Here is the entire CurFunding class it is actually `CurConstructionFunding`, but I shortened the name in the previous example:

```
namespace MfpSuite.Models.Documents.CUR
{
  public class CurConstructionFunding
  {
    [Key]
    public int CurConstructionFundingKey { get; set; }
    public int CurPropertyKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CurPropertyKey")]
    public virtual CurProperty CurProperty { get; set; }

    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Lender { get; set; }
    public string ConstructionAmount { get; set; }
    public string PermanentAmount { get; set; }
    public string PermanentLoanPerUnit { get; set; }
    public string TotalConstructionAmount { get; set; }
    public string TotalPermanentAmount { get; set; }
    public string TotalPermanentLoanPerUnit { get; set; }

    //public int CurResponseKeyId { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("CurResponseKeyId")]
    //public virtual CurResponse CurResponse { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates which funding this data is imported into.  Note there shouldn't be more than one item in this collection.
    /// 01/14/13 - todo - if there shouldn't be more than one, this should be a 1|1 mapping here (like we have [mistakenly] done w/ docTypes to Doc)
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<Cur2FundingDataFlow> Cur2FundingDataFlow { get; set; }

  }
}
```

## Edit 2

Here is what I could pull from a quickwatch of the `Find()`:

```
_db.CurConstructionFundings = {SELECT 
[Extent1].[CurConstructionFundingKey] AS [CurConstructionFundingKey], 
[Extent1].[CurPropertyKey] AS [CurPropertyKey], 
[Extent1].[Source] AS [Source], 
[Extent1].[Lender] AS [Lender], 
[Extent1].[ConstructionAmount] AS [ConstructionAmount], 
...

_db.CurConstructionFundings

{SELECT 
[Extent1].[CurConstructionFundingKey] AS [CurConstructionFundingKey], 
[Extent1].[CurPropertyKey] AS [CurPropertyKey], 
[Extent1].[Source] AS [Source], 
[Extent1].[Lender] AS [Lender], 
[Extent1].[ConstructionAmount] AS [ConstructionAmount], 
[Extent1].[PermanentAmount] AS [PermanentAmount], 
[Extent1].[PermanentLoanPerUnit] AS [PermanentLoanPerUnit], 
[Extent1].[TotalConstructionAmount] AS [TotalConstructionAmount], 
[Extent1].[TotalPermanentAmount] AS [TotalPermanentAmount], 
[Extent1].[TotalPermanentLoanPerUnit] AS [TotalPermanentLoanPerUnit]
FROM [dbo].[CurConstructionFundings] AS [Extent1]}

        StackTrace  "   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectConflicts(IList`1 entries)\r\n   
        at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()\r\n   
        at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges()\r\n   
        at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force)\r\n   
        at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)\r\n  
        at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)" string

        +       [System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo]   {Void DetectConflicts(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry])} System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the class structure of `CurFunding`? Do you see any SQL being emitted when `Find` is executing?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I didn't get any email notification from SO.

My question has been updated with the info you requested.

Comment: The problem is not the `Find` but `DetectChanges` that is called internally by `Find`. (That's also the reason why `Where...` doesn't create the exception because it does NOT call `DetectChanges` internally.) If `DetectChanges` throws such an error it means that some changes of object states happened before. Because in your Post action there is no change before `Find` I'd guess that your context `_db` is not "fresh" and something happened before, maybe even in a former request and the context hasn't been disposed properly.

Comment: I checked the entries and they state: "Enumeration yielded no results" when I quick watched the *Results View* of the entry object.

Comment: Can you try to use a fresh context: not `_db`, but instead create a new one at the beginning of the post action: `var newDb = new YourContext();`. Then use `newDB` instead of `_db` and see if the error line gets passed.

Comment: Has this issue resolved?Im also facing similar problem.Some how I am not able to get the parent objects so I am updating those manually into the object being edited and getting this error, pls help:public ActionResult Edit(Organization obj)
  {
            obj.Party = PartyRepo.Find(obj.PartyId);
            //remove the lock since it is not required for inserts
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
                OrganizationRepo.Update(obj);
    UnitOfWork.Save();
    LockSvc.Unlock(obj);
    return RedirectToAction("List");
   }
   else
   {
    return View();
   }
  }